# How do I add a checkbox in a google sheet row when a form appends a row of data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script that sends an email to email addresses referenced in rows. I use a checkbox column to select which rows (emails) i want the email to be sent to.

Unfortunately, I cant just add a full column of empty check boxes because each append row adds the new data at the end of the check-boxes, far down the sheet.

I have a function that generates a checkbox in the column required of my sheet each time i run it but am struggling to add it so that it is run every time a row is submitted from my form.

Here is the code for the page:

```
var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f8n0eRbUacX218zUTBmrOyPWp3wOpi6tOyU8v2UnQdc/edit#gid=0";

function addnewrow(rowData) {
  
  const currentdate= new Date();
  
   const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const ws=ss.getSheetByName ("districts");
  ws.appendRow([currentdate,rowData.name,rowData.email,rowData.phone,rowData.district,rowData.number,rowData.type,rowData.stalling,rowData.starter,rowData.fuel,rowData.damage,rowData.parts,rowData.service,rowData.other,rowData.comments]);
  return true;
  AddCheckBox(e)

function AddCheckBox(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("districts")  // Modified
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 14);
  range.clearContent();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Really looking to make this add the checkbox every-time the row is added
Thanks
Dan

Comment: Are you talking a bout Google forms that autmaticaly append a row of data on each form submit or do you append data from some custom form?

Comment: Hi, I am appending data through a custom form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: `return true;`

- After encountering a return statement your function will terminate. and what ever is written in the following lines will not be executed.
- Thus, `AddCheckBox(e)` will never get called

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance... an oversight and quick fix!... wrong placement of return statement. Now it works